# Firebase Rules: Different between this rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

What is the different between this type of rules? Its look like same, but I really didn't get it.

```
"rules": {
  "Users": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth !== null && data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
  }
}
```

VS

```
"rules": {
  "Users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth !== null && data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first ruleset a user can read the entire `/Users` node if they are authenticated, and if that `/Users` node contains a `uid` property with their value.

In the second ruleset a user can only read a specific subnode of `/Users`, under those same conditions. The `$` variable acts as a wildcard in the second ruleset: the rules under `/Users/$uid` apply to each specific user node.

Say you have a node `/Users` like this:

```
Users: {
  uid1: {
    name: "user 1",
    uid: "uid1"
  },
  uid2: {
    name: "user 2",
    uid: "uid2"
  },
  uid3: {
    name: "user 3",
    uid: "uid3"
  }
}
```

With the second ruleset, user `uid1` can only read their own node `/Users/uid1`. If they try to read `/Users`, they'll get `Permission denied`. And thus they're unable to get a list of all users.

Now let's make a tiny change to the JSON, adding `/Users/uid`:

```
Users: {
  uid: "uid1",
  uid1: {
    name: "user 1",
    uid: "uid1"
  },
  uid2: {
    name: "user 2",
    uid: "uid2"
  },
  uid3: {
    name: "user 3",
    uid: "uid3"
  }
}
```

Now with your first ruleset, only `uid1` can read `/Users`. Doing so will give them their own data, but also the data of every other user.